# Get unique value for input box when looping through values from a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am using javascript for a search function.

```
function searchbrand(){
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='brandid']").val();
    $.post("search-brand-vw.php", {searchVal: searchTxt})
    .done(function(brandlist) {
        $("#brandlist").html(brandlist);
    });

}
```

Here, I send the value of an input box to a separate php file. So in this page, I am populating a table from a mysql database. So there are numerous `brandid` fields. The search works as it should, for the first row of the table. But when there is a value in the first row, and when I'm doing the search on the second row, it gets the value from the first row too. How can I get the value only on the row I'm typing. FYI, there is a field named `DL_Id` in each row, which is unique. How can I use this value for this row, maybe with an AND clause?

```
var searchTxt = $("input[name='brandid']").val();
```

This is how I loop from the db

```
$query=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM dl_commfactory_2 LIMIT 35");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $dlid = $row['DL_Id'];
    $brandid = $row['Brand_Id'];
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="dlid" readonly value="<?php echo $dlid; ?>" size="2"></td>     
    <td><input type="text" name="brandid" value="<?php echo $brandid; ?>" list="brandlist" id="output" onkeyup="searchbrand()" >
    <datalist id="brandlist" name="taskoption">
        <option> </option>
    </datalist> </td>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: either exclude the all ready selected via the query or the output

Comment: @Dagon, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, change the call for searchBrand() to **searchBrand(this)**, so that you send the element being edited to the function.

Then, change the searchBrand function accordingly:

```
function searchBrand(el){
    var brandIdElement = $(el); //The element being edited
    var searchTxt = brandIdElement.val(); //The new value sent
    var searchTxtDL = brandIdElement.parents('tr').find('input[name="dlid"]').val(); //The dlid element's value in the same line

    //Send the value of the dlid too
    $.post("search-brand-vw.php", {searchVal: searchTxt, searchValDL: searchTxtDL})
    .done(function(brandlist) {
        //Get the brandList element for the specific line
        var brandListEl = brandIdElement.parents('tr').find('datalist[name="taskoption"]');
        brandListEl.html(brandlist);
    });

}
```

There are a couple of performance optimizations that can be implemented, but if performance is not an issue here then it should be OK.

Comment: why send the dlid to the other php too?

Comment: "FYI, there is a field named DL_Id in each row, which is unique. How can I use this value for this row, maybe with an AND clause?"

- 
Thinking in manipulating the query with this value, I imagine that would be the best way. Sending the value to PHP and use it in any filter directly there.